# The correct way to get the Idea right

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference

I got into arguments using

*"Wait for me for a second"*

is it actually *Wait For me For a second*
or
*Wait Me For a second*

What is the correct way of delivering the idea behind it?

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [Cambridge Dict.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/wait-or-wait-for):

Wait means

> stay in the same place or not do something until something else
> happens

so it doesn't make much sense to say ***wait me for a second.***

However, it does make sense, and actually conveys your idea if you say

> Wait for me for a second.

The page I mentioned also provides a general rule you can use to avoid making such mistakes:

> When we use a direct object after wait, we have to use wait for.

So, ***wait for me(object) for a second*** is correct.

Comment: the problem I with the sentence is that, it is kind of odd to use *for* twice in the sentence.

Comment: @RAWOKATO
"Wait for me for a second" is completely grammatically correct. You could also say "Wait a second for me".

Comment: There is no problem with repeating a little word like _for_: it is quite natural as you wrote it.

Comment: @Mohsen: In my view, it's not very helpful explaining this sort of issue in terms of meaning, because there is no intrinsic reason why _wait_ shouldn't take a direct object, as it does in some languages (eg French, _attendre_. Consider also that _expect_ does take a direct object). I think it's simpler just to say that, for no particular reason, _wait_ doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

In casual speech we can omit 'for' before a period of time, so 'wait for me a second' and 'wait **for** me for a second' are equivalent. Using 'for a second' is slightly more formal but may be felt to be unnecessary repetition of 'for'. Likewise 'I've waited a year for you' and 'I've waited for a year for you.'

Answer (score -1):

I think the right way to say it is "Wait for me for a second", you could also say "Wait for me a second."